# Beego Cannot Find Controller

Tags: rest, go, frameworks, beego

I am working on beego application. I am trying to run the same code in two different machine. Both are ubuntu. In one machine, it runs without any problem but in other I got following error log. I have the same file organization for both, why do you think this might be happening?

```
controllers/EventController.go:18: this.ServeJson undefined (type *EventController has no field or method ServeJson)
controllers/EventController.go:24: this.ServeJson undefined (type *EventController has no field or method ServeJson)
controllers/EventController.go:30: this.ServeJson undefined (type *EventController has no field or method ServeJson)
controllers/default.go:14: c.TplNames undefined (type *MainController has no field or method TplNames)
```

Even controller:

```
package controllers


import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    "solardatabase/models"
    "solardatabase/dao"
    "solardatabase/services"
)

type EventController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (this *EventController) ListEvents() {
    res := struct{ Tasks []*models.Event }{dao.GetAllEvents()}
    this.Data["json"] = res
    this.ServeJson()
}

func (this *EventController) ListEventsByRange() {
    request, _ := models.CreateEventByTimeRangeRequest(this.Ctx.Input)
    this.Data["json"] = dao.EventsByTimeRange(request)
    this.ServeJson()
}

func (this *EventController) TemporalQuery() {
    request, _ := models.CreateTemporalRequest(this.Ctx.Input)
    this.Data["json"] = services.EventsByTimeFilter(request)
    this.ServeJson()
}
```

Comment: Might be an obvious question but do you have the same dependencies on both machines? Did you do a `go get -u github.com/astaxie/beego` on the machine where it is not running?

Comment: Yes I can see all the dependencies (exactly the same directory tree) in both machines.

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem. Beego released new version between my installation of the machines. I thought it cannot see the whole controller but It was only the name of function.

In new version:

```
serveJson() -> serveJSON()
```

Config also changed.

```
Beego.HttpPort -> beego.BConfig.Listen.HTTPPort
```

Comment: -u after go get updates your existing dependency. Thus my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Beego version 1.11.1

This is case sensitive.

Change

```
this.ServeJson()
```

to

```
this.ServeJSON()
```